# Does Yocto / Bitbake have a "bulldoze" variable for recipes?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Say I have some files that are installed by a custom package of mine, but that these files will overwrite some, but not all, files installed by another package.

I would think the intuitive approach would be

1. Have my package "DEPEND" on the other one so that it installs first
2. My install stomps over files that are there first.

Unfortunately Bitbake likes to throw many errors for this approach.

Is there a "IDGAF just put them there" variable I can set?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. I have often wanted the same thing, but never found a solution. My answer is below.

Generally to do this, I fork the recipe that installs the files I want to overwrite into my own layer, and modify that recipe to install what I need in the filesystem directly. This gets complicated for things like systemd, udev, or other system applications. In those cases, if you feel like you need to overwrite system files, it might be time to rethink the design. At the best, it's difficult to maintain over time and versions. However, for simpler ideas like protobuf, watchdog, things like that, this is a perfectly acceptable mechanism to define your specific needs.

Another option is to define some functions to be done during image install to go ahead and modify files in place. I do this for our ssh configuration as a step prior to actually creating the image file itself. I create specific python functions in my image recipe and call those from image creation. I do this using

```
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "my_python_function"
```

Honestly though, you should treat this type of idea as a last resort. It's likely easier to simply use different files as necessary.

Comment: What I ended up doing is I created a bbappend with a do_install_append that deletes the binaries in the destination and replaces them with mine.